# How to configure an Extreme Networks Altitude 451 for stand-alone AP use?

Tags: wifi, access-point

I have an Extreme Networks Altitude 451 (15801) wireless N access point.  It is usually set up and managed using a controller unit, but I am hoping it is possible to configure one of these to work stand-alone, like a basic wireless access point.

It has a LAN / WAN jack, so I am assuming if it's possible, I would have to access some sort of web interface to do this.

Hoping someone has done this and can explain how, or point me to some documentation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Altitude 451's can't operate as standalone APs.  They get their config and work with the controller to operate.  Even after the central controller configures them though, you can't simply remove the controller from the network.

The only thing they can do is bridge the traffic without going through the controller, so that client->server communication only goes client > AP > network switch >> server...and doesn't have to route through the central controller, which helps if the AP is at a branch office for instance.

But a controller is still required.  They are basically thin client APs.  The new adaptive AP line they offer does allow you to do what you are asking though.